# Excel VBA Dynamically refer to UserForm TextBox and get value

Tags: excel, vba

lets say in a UserForm I have two textboxes, TextBox1 and TextBox2.
How can I dynamically refer to and get the values of these TextBoxes?

Depending on the value of a TextBox, certain other actions should be triggered.
However, I can only make it work, if I explicitly name the TextBoxes and cannot figure out, how to do it dynamically. Can anybody help me?

This works:

```
If TextBox1.Value > 0 Then
Do something
End If

If TextBox2.Value > 0 Then
Do something
End If
```

Since there are actually more than 2 TextBoxes, I imagined doing something like this but it does not work:

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to 2
If ("TextBox" & i).Value > 0 Then
Do something
End if
Next i
```

So I guess my question is, how can I combine a string (one part of the name of the TextBox, with a variable (here i) to get another variable (?) which represents the TextBoxes and from which the value can be read? Or is there another/better solution to my problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Try `me.controls("Textbox" & i)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works!
Can you explain what I did wrong,or why your way works?